# Add properties to an array of objects from a separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I need to add properties to an array of objects from a separate array.
I have 2 arrays. The first array is an array of objects. The second array is an array of Ints. I want to add a new property to each object in the array from the array of Ints.

Example:

```
var arrOfObj = [
  {
    name: "eve"
  },
  {
    name: "john"
  },
  {
    name: "jane"
  }
];

var arr = [0, 1, 2]
//Desired output

var arrOfObj = [
  {
    name: "eve",
    num: 0
  },
  {
    name: "john",
    num: 1
  },
  {
    name: "jane",
    num: 2
  }
];
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with `Array#forEach`

```js
var arrOfObj = [ { name: "eve" }, { name: "john" }, { name: "jane" }];
var arr = [0, 1, 2];

arrOfObj.forEach((a,i)=>{ a.num = arr[i]});

console.log(arrOfObj)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!